# How to return all rows that have equal number of values of 0 and 1?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe that has 50 columns each column have either 0 or 1. How do I return all rows that have an equal (tie) in the number of 0 and 1 (25 "0" and 25 "1").
An example on a 4 columns:

```
   A  B  C  D 
   1  1  0  0
   1  1  1  0
   1  0  1  0
   0  0  0  0
```

based on the above example it should return the first and the third row.

```
   A  B  C  D 
   1  1  0  0
   1  0  1  0
```

Comment: ``df.loc[df.eq(1).sum(1) == df.ne(1).sum(1)]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have four columns, we assume you must have atleast two sets of 1 in a row. So, please try

```
df[df.mean(1).eq(0.5)]
```